# TensorFlow: Save tensor variables without graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

Running python3 and Tensorflow 1.3.0 (gpu) I generate a huge number of tensorflow models, which I want to save on my disk for later evaluation. I started using the `tf.train.Saver()`, which basically does what I want. BUT its generated files are way too large. Each model takes ~3MB of HDD space, which is too much for my >10k number of models.

The only variable part in my model are the weights and biases anyway. So how hard can it be, to just save my hidden layers weights and biases in a compressed csv-file??

Then I could read those files later and create my weights- and biases-tensors again, building up my graph and use them for prediction and evaluation.

Here is part of my code. I just want to save the tensors on my disk:

```
    weights = {'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
        [self.config.n_input,
         self.config.hidden_layer_nums[0]]))}
    ...
    weights['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
        [self.config.hidden_layer_nums[-1], self.config.n_output]))
```

*So my Questions are:*

1. How can I dump a Tensor to .csv (or json) file?
2. How can I recreate a Tensor from a .csv file?

Comment: well, you could simply use python's I/O library to save and read what you want from a file.

Comment: Thx, but im quite new to python.could you show an example how to create and fill a tensor?